# jQuery mobile 1.0, will it support windows mobile 6.5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

We are developing a web application in jQuery mobile. I'm testing my application in Windows mobile 6.5. In that, jQuery mobile 1.0 and jQuery 1.6.4 plugins were used.
I want to know whether jQuery mobile 1.0, will support to Windows mobile 6.5 (Samsung omnia 652)

Can any one help me?

Comment: shirley you mean will windoze mobile support javascript, not will javascript support windoze mobile (obvious troll is obvious)

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/11/16/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-0/#platforms : A-grade support for windows phone 7+, c-grade support for windows mobile (Basic, non-enhanced HTML experience that is still functional)

Comment: what you meant by C-grade, what are the features not supported in windows mobile 6.5. Can you please provide any link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/ Windows Phone 7 and 7.5 are supported. It further lists WinMo 5.2 as having C-grade support. From experience, I know Windows Mobile 6.5 does support some javascript but I'd have to get my old phone out to see what it does with jqmobile.

Also according to the linked page:

> We use a 3-level graded platform support system: A (full), B (full
>   minus Ajax), C (basic). The visual fidelity of the experience is
>   highly dependent on the CSS rendering capabilities of the device and
>   platform so not all A grade experience will be pixel-perfect but
>   that’s the nature of the web.